How to subscribe to queue in ActiveMQ Artemis using MQTT?
I'm having a problem with ActiveMQ Artemis subscribing to queue using MQTT. When I subscribe to a specific address the broker creates a new temporary queue named deviceID.address despite having queue to join. For example, I have a queue test with address test, and when I send a subscription with topic test the broker creates a new non-durable queue with a name DeviceID.test, and I don't know what the proper syntax is to subscribe to the right queue.
I tried all the combinations for exampled only address or adress/queue, and I can't find the proper syntax to subscribing.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What you described is the expected behavior. Why do you need to subscribe to an existing queue?

Any feedback here?

The MQTT protocol supports subscribing to topics to achieve pub/sub semantics. If you read through the MQTT specification you'll find no mention of subscribing to a queue. The behavior you're seeing is expected.
That said, ActiveMQ Artemis supports the ability to specify the fully qualified queue name (i.e. FQQN) which I believe you can use from your MQTT subscriber. In your case, the FQQN would be test::test.
You might want to ensure your use of MQTT actually fits your overall use-case. You might should use a different protocol if you really need the point-to-point semantics of a queue.
